# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element C# Find By Class

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, mstest

```
Message: 
Test method CFSSOnlineBanking.SmokeTests.TransferDisplay threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#menuLeftRailContainer > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)

Stack Trace: 
RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CssSelector>b__0(ISearchContext context)
By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
TransferPage.get_TransferLink() line 22
SmokeTests.TransferDisplay() line 57
```

I am currently trying to click on a href that is located inside a div. No matter what I try it seems like I cannot click on it.
[image]

Here is the element when I inspect it.
[image]

I have tried adding a wait I have tried clicking by LinkText, PartialLinkText, cssSelector and xPATH

Currently I have this in my TransferPage Class:

```
public IWebElement TransferLink => _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#menuLeftRailContainer > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)"));
```

And then in my actual test method I have:

```
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
transferPage.TransferLink.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following

**xpath :**

```
//a[@href='/connect-native/transfer/']
```

**or css selector**

```
a[href='/connect-native/transfer/']
```

**In code  :**

```
public IWebElement TransferLink => _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='/connect-native/transfer/']"));
```

cause the css selector you have used in your code, looks bit messy. Are you sure there is 1/1 matching element with that ?

if this does not work, can you look for iframes in your webpage ?

Comment: It looks like there isn't an iframe at least for that section and I just tried implementing the other suggestions with no luck....

Comment: It looks like it is the same OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='/connect-native/transfer/']"}

Comment: Did you check in dom ? Is there 1/1 matching node ?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  and see if your desired element is getting highlighted

Comment: Okay, that is what I was doing. Yeah it is being highlighted....

Comment: No such element exception is cause either the locators are not correct or we have iframe, or probably page loading issue. and make sure to launch the browser in full screen mode